# Liu, Proposition 8.1.12: inverse image of blown-up ideal sheaf is invertible

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup

I am struggling with Proposition 8.1.12e of Liu's Algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves.
The setup is as follows: let $X=\text{Spec}A$, $I=(f_1,\dots,f_n)\subseteq A$ an ideal, and let
$$\tilde A=\bigoplus_{d\ge0}I^d.$$
We distinguish $I\subseteq\tilde A_0=A$ and $I=\tilde A_1$ by denoting with $t_1,\dots,t_n\in\tilde A_1$ the elements corresponding to $f_1,\dots,f_n\in A$ respectively.
If $\mathscr{I}=\tilde{I}$ in $X$ and $\tilde X=\text{Proj}\tilde A$, the proof of Proposition 8.1.12e says that $\mathscr{I}\mathcal{O}|_{D_+(t_i)}$ is generated by $f_i$ for every $1\le i\le n$ because $f_j=f_i(t_jt_i^{-1})$, i.e.
$$\mathscr{I}\mathcal{O}|_{D_+(t_i)}=f_i\mathcal{O}_{D_+(t_i)}$$
Then, the claim is that
$$\mathscr{I}\mathcal{O}_{D_+(t_i)}=\mathcal{O}_{D_+(t_i)}(1)$$
I don't understand this for two reasons:

- Since $D_+(t_i)$ is an affine scheme, how can you take the twist $\mathcal{O}_{D_+(t_i)}(1)$? Isn't it more correct to write it as $\mathcal{O}(1)|_{D_+(t_i)}$?
- Assuming $\mathcal{O}_{D_+(t_i)}(1)=\mathcal{O}(1)|_{D_+(t_i)}$, if I try to calculate it I get
  $$\mathcal{O}(1)_{D_+(t_i)}=(\tilde{A}(1)_{(t_i)})\tilde{}=(t_i\tilde{A}_{(t_i)})\tilde{}=t_i\mathcal{O}_{D_+(t_i)}.$$

But $t_i\mathcal{O}_{D_+(t_i)}\neq f_i\mathcal{O}_{D_+(t_i)}$, so how is $\mathscr{I}\mathcal{O}_{D_+(t_i)}=\mathcal{O}_{D_+(t_i)}(1)$ true?

Comment: I agree that something strange is happening here: $\mathscr{I}\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}}$ is supposed to made with homogeneous elements of degree zero, while $\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}}(1)$ with homogeneous elements of degree one… I think your first point is correct (but minor). But I don’t have the book (and this passage doesn’t show up in the various errata lists), so I can’t say for sure.